# Is it possible to define the height of a row in a UITableView without an UITableViewController?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I've created a class that inherits from UITableViewSource and another one from UITableViewCell. I'm not using an UITableViewController, because I am adding other views in an UIViewController. I was wondering if I could change the height of the rows because my height is kinda large because it has a "preview information" in it. But it is currently very small, and the solutions that I've found all include an UITableViewController because it has:

```
TableView.RowHeight = UITableView.AutomaticDimension;
TableView.EstimatedRowHeight = 40f;
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Sure, I think you will give a fixed height to TableView in the UIViewController and once the RowHeight grows, the content inside TableView will be scrollable. Actually, UITableViewController is a  UIViewController with a TableView which height is the height of screen, it's the same.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow memyselfandi! It's not possible to have a class that inherits from two different classes in C#. Could you please share the code of the class in question? If you want to set the row height, then generally in the class that inherits from the UITableViewSource, you will override the `GetHeightForRow()` function similar to this: `public override nfloat GetHeightForRow(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)        {    return new nfloat(66);}`

Comment: Hello Saamer!
Thank you so muchh!!!!!! It worked! :D :D :D

Comment: @Saamer you should post the comment as an answer so memyselfandi can mark it as the valid answer. That will help others in the future.

Comment: @pinedax thanks, updated. I just wasn't sure what the problem was initially

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set the row height, then generally in the class that inherits from the `UITableViewSource`, you will override the `GetHeightForRow()` function similar to this:

```
public override nfloat GetHeightForRow(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath) 
{ 
    return new nfloat(66);
}
```

Comment: hello. I'm sorry to bother again but how can I adjust the row height to fit my labels? I'm going to update the question to show you my code. The value that I wanted is the "test" but I am not being able to send it to the "override nfloat GetHeightForRow"

Comment: There's multiple ways of doing this. One way is to DequeueReusableCell and figure out which cell type you are showing. Once you figure that out, just place a switch-case depending on the cell type and adjust height accordingly.